# I just installed ubuntu 16.04 to my laptop containing windows 7, deselected erase drive and selected use lvm

Tags: boot

i did not attempt to erase windows seven but now all i'm seeing is ubuntu. Tell me how to access my windows 7 os please

Comment: did you tell LVM to use the whole drive?

Comment: im not sure that I told lvm to use the whole drive

Comment: run `lsblk` and add the results to your question.

Comment: I ran it but I cant figure out how to post it here...i took a picture of the results

Comment: can't get online with the laptop wifi doesn't seem to be picking up my internet

Answer (score 0):

Enter into the BIOS
  and in boot options if any of windows boot is visible or not
If not then definitely it must not present in your system.

and as you have stated use lvm (logical volume ) itcan be the reason to not showing the windows because it installs on primary partition of hard disk
but it not deletes ypur windows

so 
just check it in BIOS 
or check it in GPARTED application in ubuntu if windows boot loader is 
present in your system or not

Hope it could help you...

Comment: explain how to check it in bios or GPARTED.   I searched around and typed this in the terminal sudo update-grub and I dont think im seeing windows. I am completely new to linux

Comment: i took a picture of what I am seeing after entering that command but I dont know how to post it here

Comment: You can uplaod the image at imgur.com and share the link with us

Comment: https://imgur.com/USyEvVl

Comment: I tried to understand it and it seems as if windows is gone, is it?

Comment: Repair the boot using following link   https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair&ved=2ahUKEwic1LPHzvTYAhUJQo8KHYN7BuEQFjAAegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw3iJYUZ42a7jskQGCRBqbHB

Comment: It will detect the windows if present and shows the grub menu..best luck